# Script for renaming files with logical

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Someone has very kindly help get me started on a mass rename script for renaming PDF files.

As you can see I need to add a bit of logical to stop the below happening - so something like add a unique number to a duplicate file name?

```
rename 's/^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/' *

rename -n 's/^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/' *
Annexes 123114345234525.pdf renamed as Annex.pdf
Annexes 123114432452352.pdf renamed as Annex.pdf
```

Hope this makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to rename files to prefix of their names? It won't change their order, won't save typing since completion is supported in all common contexts of typing filenames and it will loose information as the numbers probably do make some sense in some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *
do
    x=''                     # counter
    j="${i:0:2}"             # new name
    e="${i##*.}"             # ext
    while [ -e "$j$x" ]      # try to find other name
    do
        ((x++))              # inc counter
    done
    mv "$i" "$j$x"           # rename
done
```

---

#### before

```
$ ls
he.pdf  hejjj.pdf  hello.pdf  wo.pdf  workd.pdf  world.pdf
```

#### after

```
$ ls
he.pdf  he1.pdf  he2.pdf  wo.pdf  wo1.pdf  wo2.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This should check whether there will be any duplicates:

```
rename -n [...] | grep -o ' renamed as .*' | sort | uniq -d
```

If you get any output of the form `renamed as [...]`, then you have a collision.

Of course, this won't work in a couple corner cases - If your files contain newlines or the literal string `renamed as`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9499980/724357) on your previous question:

```
for f in *.pdf; do 
    tmp=`echo $f | sed -r 's/^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/'`
    mv -b ./"$f" ./"$tmp"
done
```

That will make backups of deleted or overwritten files. A better alternative would be this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $*; do
    tar -rvf /tmp/backup.tar $f
    tmp=`echo $f | sed -r 's/^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/'`
    i=1
    while [ -e tmp ]; do
        tmp=`echo $tmp | sed "s/\./-$i/"`
        i+=1
    done
    mv -b ./"$f" ./"$tmp"
done
```

Run the script like this:

```
find . -exec thescript '{}' \;
```

The [find](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command gives you lots of options for specifing which files to run on, works recursively, and passes all the filenames in to the script. The script backs all file up with tar (uncompressed) and then renames them.

This isn't the best script, since it isn't smart enough to avoid the manual loop and check for identical file names.

Comment: @kev I got the shebang, did I miss anything else?

Comment: `for ...; do`, `while ...; do`, `i+=1`, etc